# How to add a point inside \newtheorem (definition)?

Tags: newtheorem, definition

Good day, please give me the idea to add the point right after number of the definition?
[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}[something]
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you use the optional ,argument, it is normal the punctuation be after this argument. If you want to change that, you can do it with the  `thmtools` package, but it will look weird, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that the present punctuation is correct, probably I have to discuss that with my book publisher. Probably they recommend me that "point" by mistake. Thank you for recommendation of thmtools package!

Comment: Æsthetically, I'd try to have the optional argument also in boldface.

Answer (score 1):

Following Bernard's suggestions in the comments, you can do this with the thmtools style key `headformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat={\NAME\ \NUMBER.\NOTE\,},
  headpunct={},
  notefont=\bfseries,
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep
  ]{mydefstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=mydefstyle,
  parent=section
  ]{definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{definition}[something]
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: defs]